# The system cannot find the file specified - Netbeans Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I need to read two .json files, I have added them to my src folder of NetBeans folder but it is not finding the file.

**I have tried** using path in following ways,

```
"/krf_input_cases.json", 
"krf_input_cases.json", 
"/com.mycompany.reasoner/krf_input_cases.json"
```

after checking here on StackOverflow but it is not working. The still same error that file cannot be found!

Here you can see where is my file is in the document tree: 
[image]

This is where I have specified my file paths

```java
//file paths
private static final String KRF_INPUT_CASES = "krf_input_cases.json";
private static final String KRF_KNOWLEDGE_BASE = "krf_knowledge_base.json";
```

Here is the function reading the file which is throwing an exception!

```java
public static String loadData(String filePath) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("line");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            new File(filePath)));} catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
    System.out.println("line1");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line.trim());

    }
    br.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find a suitable duplicate with good answers, but there definetly have been questions about this. Basically you cannot assume that you have access to the source code directories after deploying the app. Depending on the project setup those files may be available via classpath and this is how you should access resources like these. Use `Class.getResourceAsStream` to get an `InputStream` containing the data for the classpath entry: `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/reasoner/krf_input_cases.json")`

Comment: The `json` files should be in the `resources` folder, and then use `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()` to access them, as pointed out by @fabian.